# Div Positioning Library for UI Layout in Html/CSS?

Tags: javascript, css, html, user-interface, user-experience

One thing I've always hated is the complexity of positioning divs in CSS. horizontal align, vertical align (and no, not with auto-margins, etc). Vertical and Horizontal positioning within parent containers, (ie cascading), etc. Grouping two things side by side (and no, not with floats, or tables, or ul/li or the other hacks out there), etc. I'd also like different types of containers. If you're familiar with wpf, they have vertical/horizontal stack containers, and positioning containers is usually done easily just with declaring something as 'left aligned, centered,' and it always takes the parent containers' position into account too.

Is there a library on github or something that handles 'containers' and 'positioning'? This is mainly for UI layout in app development (either desktop or mobile) but html5 based. Either by declaring custom attributes in html or css (preferable) or by javascript programming?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's really nothing that complicated about using CSS to position elements once you have a grasp on it. If you want to get things to stack responsively for an app with different viewports use a responsive grid framework, this one is very easy to use for a beginner:

http://getskeleton.com/

For even more control use flexbox (depending on your browser support needs):

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: you're kidding me right? nothing complicated. try to center text within a div (text-align) try to center a div horizontally when the position is static (margin:auto) vs absolute (margin:auto,left:0/right:0), and don't forget to specify a width. try to center text vertically in a div. (what is it line-height). css is a spaghetti mess. complete trash whoever designed it. sorry.

Comment: Without getting into a debate here, millions of people everyday use to CSS to create a plethora of different websites. Positioning in CSS is not challenging, and I usually find those that complain about the difficulty of a language those to be the ones that don't fully understand it. CSS is still developing, and with the addition of flexbox it has become even easier to position elements. Instead of moaning about how terrible it is and trying to find a javascript framework (you won't find one, its completely the wrong way of doing things) maybe try learning more about CSS.

Comment: I think the answer I was looking for was flexbox. there's alot to it, but I think it's what I was wanting all along.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out twitter bootstrap in case you haven't heard of it, its the most popular front end framework. It has a grid system that is pretty simple to utilize http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html#gridSystem

It will allow you to create a layout with relative ease.
I do recommend learning eventually learning how to do this stuff yourself though

Comment: I've looked into bootstrap, it's a bit heavy for what I want though